# How to modify the value for the reducer object with a new key and value on matching the item in the reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it possible in redux, to call a action which modify the reducer particular item on matching the item so as to modify it with the item with a new key followed by some new value.

Comment: please add an example

Answer (score 0):

It will be great if you can show some example since this is how redux works, you dispatch the action then in reducer base of action type you modify the state.